# Limits at infinity for sequences and funtions

Tags: real-analysis

First recall the definitions

> **Definition I**: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real or complex numbers. We say that $a_n\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$, if
>   $$
> \forall R>0 \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}:[(n\geq N)\implies (a_n>R) ].
> $$
>
> **Definition II**: Let $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$, where $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not bounded above. We say that $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$, if
>   $$
> \forall R>0\, \exists K\in\mathbb{R}\, \forall x\in D: [(x\geq K)\implies (f(x)>R)].
> $$

**Question**: Let $f:[1,\infty)\to \mathbb{C}$, and let $a_n=f(n)$ for $n\geq 1$. It is clear that if $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, then $a_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ (i.e. Definition II implies Definition I). Does the converse direction hold in general? If we assume that $a_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, then there are a lot of "gaps" (i.e. the elements of $[1,\infty)\setminus \mathbb{N}$) that should be checked in Definition II.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. We can easily imagine a function that goes to hell and back between integers and yet always is "nice" on the integers.  For example $f(x) = x\cos(2\pi*x)$ for $a_n= f(n) = n$ it's clear $a_n\to \infty$ but between integers will go way up and way down and it's clear definition 2 fails. .. Oooh.... also if $b_n = f(n + \frac 12)=-n-\frac 12\to -\infty$. We can't conclude *both* $f(x)\to \pm \infty$.  And just to be *really* annoying $c_n = f(n+\frac 14)=(n+\frac 14)(2n\pi + \frac \pi 2) =0$.  So $c_n\to 0$.  ... we're.... boned if we try to conclude that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that $f(n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ does not imply $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. But I would not say things like "Definition II implies Definition I" because the two definitions intrinsically have nothing to do with each other. You've forced a connection with the definition $a_n = f(n)$, but as you pointed out, the behavior of $f$ at natural numbers $n$ does not govern the behavior of $f$ anywhere else.

---

Concrete counterexample:

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if }x \in \mathbb{N} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.
If $a_n = f(n)$ then $a_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. But $f(x) \not\to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

A good counter example is $f(x) = x\cos(2\pi x)$ and

$a_n = f(n); b_n = f(n+\frac 12);$ $c_n = f(n + \frac 14)$

$a_n = n\cos (2\pi n) = n \to \infty$

$b_n = (n+\frac 12)\cos ((2n + 1)\pi)=-n -\frac 12 \to -\infty$

$c_n =(n+\frac 1r) \cos(2n\pi + \frac \pi 2) = (n+\frac 14)\cdot 0 = 0\to 0$.

Clearly we can't conclude anything about the limits of $f(x)$ by the limits of $a_n, b_n$ and $c_n$.

(Have you had the theorem that if a sequence converges then all subsequence converge to the same limit?  If so this should be clear. If not this should give you a really good idea we the theorem holds.)

And if we actually try to find the limit if $f(x)$.

For Any $R >0$ and all $K \in \Bbb R$  we can find $x > \max (|K|+1, R); x \in \mathbb N$ so $f(x+\frac 12) = -x-\frac 12 < -|K|-1 < K$ so $\lim f(x) \ne \infty$.

And $f(x) = x > |K|+1 > K$ so $\lim f(x) \ne -\infty$

and for $0< \epsilon < 1$  $|f(x)-K| = ||K|+1 - K| \ge 1 > \epsilon$ so $\lim f(x) \ne K$.

So $f(x)$ does not converge to any value nor does it converge to infinity or negative infinity.

SO... Yes, you are correct.